# How to call functions and classes of a wsdl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wsdl

Im a newbie to asp.net and i have a wsdl and in it when i create a object for the service it shows "cannot create object for abstract class"

so how can i use this wsdl and call the web service?

```
sampleservice object = new sampleservice (cannot able to create object)

   public class Demo : sampleservice .sampleservice 
{
    // public string auth_string = "ssampleservice ampleservice ";
     //public string country_iso = "MY";
     sampleservice .used_amount_data useramount = new sampleservice .used_amount_data();
     sampleservice .GlobalResponse globalresponse = new sampleservice .GlobalResponse();
     sampleservice .CDRPage cdrpage = new sampleservice .CDRPage();
     sampleservice .RegionsExt[] regionext = new sampleservice .RegionsExt[]{};
     sampleservice .api_sampleservice apidata = new sampleservice .api_didwwdata();
     sampleservice .City[] city = new sampleservice .City[] { };
     sampleservice .Country[] country = new sampleservice .Country[] { };
     sampleservice .Rates[] rates = new sampleservice .Rates[] { };
     sampleservice .Regions[] regions = new sampleservice .Regions[] { };
     sampleservice .prepaid_data prepaiddata = new sampleservice .prepaid_data();
```

so how can i retrieve it from abstract class

Comment: you cannot retrieve from abstract, because by definition, it's abstract and you can't instantiate it. You'll need to inherit from it and use that.

Comment: the wsdl contains all functions and class parameters , ok inherite how to get result from the functions

Answer (score 0):

> so how can i retrieve it from abstract class

Simple answer, You can't. If your service WSDL just has the abstruct class, that means there is no implementation present for your service (OR) the service you are trying to consume.

See if you have a concrete class that implements your service and try creating proxy object using that class.

If you really want to use/Inherit that service abstruct class, then consider getting the service project `dll` and consume the same.

Comment: how can i create proxy object can you elobarate it??

Comment: they provide only wsdl web service not dll so how to consume it??

Comment: That's what I said, your service must have a implementation class/a concrete class. Use that class to create a proxy.

Comment: but how to create a proxy using that class??

Comment: suppose if the class is interface what can i do??

Comment: @dazzlingkumar, I think you should first consider learning about C# and OOP.